# How to read selected builtin parameters of sklearn grid search estimators?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm using sklearn 'gridsearchcv' to find the best hyper-parameters of my feature selection method, here 'selectkbest'. I'm useing a pipeline of 'feature selection' and my ridge regression on top of it.

An example of such pipeline is [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_compare_reduction.html).

However, I'm using ['RidgeCV'](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html) which chooses it's own regularizer with an efficient builtin loocv. In this case I'm not able to access the parameters of my Ridgecv.

```
k_range = [10, 15, 30, 50, 150, 300, 500]
alpha_range = [0.01, 0.05, 
           0.1, 0.5, 
           1,
           2,
           5, 
            10,
            100]
featureSelection = SelectKBest(f_classif)
ridgecv = linear_model.RidgeCV(alphas=alpha_range, gcv_mode='eigen', 
                           store_cv_values=True)
pipe = Pipeline([('anova', featureSelection), ('ridgecv', ridgecv)])
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid={'anova__k':k_range}, 
cv=inner_cv)
grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(grid.best_params_)
```

In putput of this code I can see what is the selected k for 'anova' feature selection but I can't find a way to access the chosen 'alpha' for my 'ridgecv'

```
{'anova__k': 15}
```

I try to get the best estimator and read it's alpha parameter like this:

```
es = grid.estimator.named_steps['ridgecv'].score(x,y)
es.alpha_
```

But it says:

```
NotFittedError: This RidgeCV instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try `best_estimator_` instead of `estimator`, ie

```
es = grid.best_estimator_.named_steps['ridgecv']
```

On a different topic, while strictly functional, it is strange to have cross-validation both at `RidgeCV` level and at `GridSearchCV` level. In this case, I would suggest working with the `sklearn.linear_model.Ridge` class and have the cross-validation of alpha at the `GridSearchCV` level, e.g.

```
ridge = Ridge()
pipe = Pipeline([('anova', featureSelection), ('ridge', ridge)])
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid={'anova__k':k_range, 'ridge__alpha': alpha_range})
```